# Failed to load data inside of iFrame

Tags: html, reactjs, sockets, websocket

I tried to fetch the URL of an old website, and an error happened:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://xyz.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://abc' is therefore not allowed access.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

my code looks like this

```
render(){
    return (
       <div>
          <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/.../StockExchangeWidget.html" />
       </div>
    )
}
```

when I load this outside of iFrame, everything is OK, but when I try to load it with iFrame well then I get lot's of errors, but only for data for charts, as you can see the frame and buttons are loaded.

[image]

I'm also getting WebSocket error when I try to load HTML page over url inside of 
WebSocket connection to 'wss://widgetdata.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=widgetembed%2F&date=2018_06_09-17_59' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Answer (score 1):

The domain that hosts the iframe needs to amend its [CORS Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to allow requests from your domain to reach their site. Without the CORS headers present on that page, your browser will not render the content of the iframe (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is in the [CORS Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) as PANAYIOTIS pointed to me.

my code now looks like this

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>    
            <iframe
                sandbox="allow-same-origin"
                title="FirstIFrame"
                src="http://www.tricky.web.siteHome.do"
            />    
        </div>
    )
}
```

I added **sandbox="allow-same-origin"** inside of my iframe, and all 'cookies' and 'can not upload' problems are solved.

for more info read [this post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) It's great for this kind of problems: